# CSS div shifting elements down

Tags: html, css

I am working on my portfolio and I am having an issue with the project description shifting the images on the left downward when the browser resize. A picture of the issue here: click here When you resize the browser the text will shift over and move the images down. I've tried setting min-width but that doesn't help the text nor the image div to make sure it doesn't resize at a certain point.

Here is a sample link to the page itself: [click here][2]

I tried adding min-widths to a image element but that doesn't work either. I do not want to use absolute position as it will overlap on top on resize. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to happen? A horizontal scrollbar to appear?

Comment: No I just want the elements not to shift at all and remain in their places.

Comment: You've got an image that is 1000+ px wide, and you specified the width of your description to 350Px.  Therefore any time you resize your browser to be less than 1350px (not factoring in margins or padding) the images will jump...it is the proper behavior of the browser.  Specifying the width of your image wrapper would allow you to scroll horizontally, but is that the ultimate solution (eg) do you really need an image that big)?  Personally, I hate scrolling horizontally on a site that wasn't designed for it just as much as I hate browsing on a page with messed up floats.

Comment: thanks kjl, youre correct and i will consider resizing my images and making sure that the max width is more appropriate.

Comment: Hello all - I've fixed the issue by adding max and min widths to the divs and making everything a lot smaller. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an image that is 1052px wide, which is in a UL element that has a margin-left of 1.5em. Your description box is 350px. Basically your `#imagewrapper` div needs to be equal to or wider than all of these elements.

Right now that's about 1422px. It will change if the effective font size for your `UL.imagewrap-pad` changes.

That's a pretty wide web site. You probably should make it a bit narrower if you're making it for general viewing, especially with all the tablets etc out there now.

Anyway, the code you want is

```
#imagewrapper
{
  width:1422px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

The second line makes it center on the screen.

P.S - get Firebug for Firefox, or use similar tools in chrome. They let you *endlessly* experiment with styles to find out what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem just set the "width" property in #imagewrapper :

```
#imagewrapper {
    width: 1430px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the project description then shifts over to the left. I was wondering if there was a way to keep it in place under the menus of the right?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried setting up width attr on the parent element to around 1800px?

> div#imagewrapper {
>     width:1800px;
>   }

It will put a scroll bar at the bottom of Your browser, but if You want to put such a big image beside that text then You do need a lot of space. Just keep in mind that it won't fit in users monitors.
To make it look nice I guess You should apply that attribute to the body tag.